# Send array in fetch body Node

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, node-fetch

I need to send an array in the body of a fetch request. The value fields has to be an array with lastName and some other values. How do I go about this? I've tried

```
         let fields = JSON.stringify({ lastName: "test" });
```

but that did not work. I'm trying to do this in node.js. This is the code:

```
        const params = new URLSearchParams();

        params.append("name", name);
        params.append("email", email);
        params.append("fields", fields);

        fetch(url, {
          headers: Authorization,
          method: "POST",
          body: params,
        })
          .then((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          })
```

The request itself works fine, it's just fields that isn't picked up.

Comment: you said you need to send an array. Your example was not an array. Which is it?

Comment: Did you try something like. `let fields = JSON.stringify([{ lastName: "test" }, { lastName: "test" }, { lastName: "test" }])` ?

Comment: The param 'fields' has to be an array. From the docs: 
fields  array  An array with additional fields

Comment: And yes, I have tried that but that did not work. I assume they mean an associative array like you've got in PHP, which is why I figured I'd try to use an object

Comment: Ok, sorry didnt read carefully. What is not coming through? What docs? Where are you sending this data?

Comment: No worries, I'm thankful you're even taking the time to help me! I'm trying to use this https://developer.enormail.eu/#contacts-add. It's just the fields that isn't coming through, name, email etc are working fine